# how explain tbl_rows smaller than estimated_visible_rows

Tags: amazon-redshift

by analyzing the SVV_TABLE_INFO table on my cluster,
I noticed that for some table the tbl_rows value was smaller than the estimated_visible_rows value ; Sometimes the gap is very large
I did some tests, like running an Analyze or a vaccum but it didn't change anything
how explain tbl_rows smaller than estimated_visible_rows

Answer (score 0):

I see a similar issue where tbl_rows is 36,862,261 where as estimated_visible_rows is 229,512,224.
Even after vacuum to 100 percent followed by analyze; tbl_rows is 36,862,261 and estimated_visible_rows is 229,512,224.
However, it says in [https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-vacuum-performance/#:~:text=The%20estimated_visible_rows%20is%20the%20number,and%20unsorted%20should%20reach%200](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redshift-vacuum-performance/#:%7E:text=The%20estimated_visible_rows%20is%20the%20number,and%20unsorted%20should%20reach%200). that "After a complete vacuum (delete and sort), the value for tbl_rows and estimated_visible_rows should resemble each other..."